# Difficult infinite trigonometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, contest-math

Evaluate the sum of the following infinite series.

$$\left(\sin{\frac{\pi}{3}}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{2\pi}{3}}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3}\sin{\frac{3\pi}{3}}\right) + \ldots$$

Answer (score 6):

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}n=$Img$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac
{(e^{ix})^n}n\right)$

Now, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac
{(e^{ix})^n}n=-\ln(1-e^{ix})$

Again, $\displaystyle1-e^{2iy}=-e^{iy}(e^{iy}-e^{-iy})=-e^{iy}2i\sin y$

$\displaystyle\implies\ln(1-e^{2iy})=\log2+iy+\ln(\sin y)+\text{Log}(-i)$

and $\displaystyle\text{Log}(-i)=\text{Log}\left[\cos\left(-\frac\pi2\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac\pi2\right)\right]=\text{Log}_ee^{\left(2n\pi -\frac\pi2\right)i}$

$\displaystyle\implies\text{Log}(-i)=\left(2n\pi -\frac\pi2\right)i$

Here $\displaystyle 2y=x=\frac\pi3$

Comment: Very nice! This is the proper and rigorous approach!

Comment: @Lucian, Thanks for your feedback. The sum seems to be  $=\frac\pi3$

Answer (score 2):

The result is none other than $\dfrac\pi3$ , with the obvious generalization $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}n=\frac{\pi-x^*}2$, where $x^*=x\mod2\pi.~$ Unfortunately, the only way in which I am able to “prove” this is by ascribing finite values to divergent series by way of analytic continuation, which isn't really “kosher”, so $...$

Comment: With the added observation that $x\neq2k\pi$, in which case the sum is $0$ instead of $\dfrac\pi2$