# Evaluating $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\left(\pi n/k\right)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

Recently, I was asked by a friend to compute the limit of the following series

> $$\displaystyle{\lim_{k\to\infty}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{k}\right)}{n}$$

Having seen a similar problem to this before, [Difficult infinite trigonometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769794/difficult-infinite-trigonometric-series), I used the same complex argument approach as seen in that problem.

[image]

Ultimately, for this problem, I obtained $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as my answer. However, this limit can also be interpreted as a Riemann Sum, except the answer to the Riemann Sum differs from what I obtained as my answer, and according to Wolfram Alpha, the answer is expressed in terms of $Si$, where $Si$ is the sine integral.

> I'm wondering, does the limit invalidate the argument approach, or is there something else I'm missing, because this limit if I'm not mistaken is a Riemann Sum after all?

Comment: In a Riemann sum we would have both 'variables' tending to infinity simultaneously. In this case we have both $n$ and $k$ tending to infinity seperately and hence the Riemann sum approach should not be possible. This approach seems valid.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that! Guess you learn something new every day haha

Comment: Nor can you (directly) apply dominated cvg theorem ...

Comment: You effectively have $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}f(N,k)$ (where $N$ denotes the maximum summation bound). With a Riemann sum we would have $\lim_{N\to\infty}f(N)$ where $k$ may be used as an index such that the function $f(N)$ is of the form $\frac1N\sum_{k=1}^N g(k/N)\to\int_0^1g(x)\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: (Rephrasing of what Peter says) You have $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{\sin(\pi n/k)}{(n/k)} \to \int_{0}^{1} \frac{sin(\pi x)}{x} dx$ by Riemann sum argument; but you have to manage a larger interval here... ($n\ge 1$, not just $n=1...k$)

Comment: @Olivier So essentially that was the answer Wolfram gave when converted to a Riemann sum, it converged to Si(pi) but that doesn't equal pi/2, so I'm mainly concerned with what finite value this series converges to, if it all?

Comment: You can do a collection of Riemann sums to deal with n=1...k, then n=k+1...2k, n=2k+1...3k, but you would then need a further argument to put these sums altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Riemann Sum would be
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n}
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n/k}\frac1k\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\pi x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\[3pt]
&=\frac\pi2\tag1
\end{align}
$$
However, a cleaner way is to note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n}
&=-\mathrm{Im}\!\left(\log\left(1-e^{i\pi/k}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac\pi2-\frac\pi{2k}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
and the limit is easy.

---

**Take Care**

One must be careful with the convergence of the Riemann Sum. Here is one method to control the remainders.

Because $|\sin(\pi x)|\le1$, we have
$$
\int_m^{m+1}\left|\frac{\sin(\pi x)}x\right|\,\mathrm{d}x
\le\frac1m\tag3
$$
Furthermore, $\int_m^{m+2}\sin(\pi x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$, thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_m^{m+2}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\right|
&=\left|\int_m^{m+2}\sin(\pi x)\left(\frac1x-\frac1{m+1}\right)\mathrm{d}x\right|\\
&\le\frac1{m(m+1)}+\frac1{(m+1)(m+2)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac1m-\frac1{m+2}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, for any $N\ge m$,
$$
\left|\int_m^N\frac{\sin(\pi x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\right|
\le\frac1m\tag5
$$
Because $|\sin(\pi x)|\le1$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=mk}^{(m+1)k}\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n}\right|
\le\frac1m\tag6
$$
Furthermore, $\sum\limits_{n=mk}^{(m+2)k}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)=0$, thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=mk}^{(m+2)k}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n}\right|
&=\left|\sum_{n=mk}^{(m+2)k}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)\left(\frac1n-\frac1{(m+1)k}\right)\right|\\
&\le\frac1{m(m+1)}+\frac1{(m+1)(m+2)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac1m-\frac1{m+2}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, for any $M\ge mk$,
$$
\left|\sum_{n=mk}^M\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n}\right|\le\frac1m\tag8
$$
For any $\epsilon\gt0$, let $m\ge\frac4\epsilon$. Then Riemann Sums allow us to choose a $k$ large enough so that
$$
\left|\int_0^m\frac{\sin(\pi x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x-\sum_{n=1}^{mk}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n/k}\frac1k\right|\le\frac\epsilon2\tag9
$$
Inequalities $(5)$ and $(8)$ show that for any $N\ge m$ and $M\ge mk$,
$$
\left|\int_m^N\frac{\sin(\pi x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\le\frac\epsilon4
\quad\text{and}\quad
\left|\sum_{n=mk}^M\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n/k}\frac1k\right|\le\frac\epsilon4\tag{10}
$$
Inequalities $(9)$ and $(10)$ show that, for the $k$ chosen for $(9)$,
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n}-\frac\pi2\right|\le\epsilon\tag{11}
$$
Since $\epsilon\gt0$ was arbitrary, $(11)$ says that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}k\right)}{n}=\frac\pi2\tag{12}
$$

Comment: Riemann sums works on a finite intervals; what's the additional argument used here to extend this to (0,\infty) ?

Comment: I've gotta say, that is one sexy solution and elegant approach! +1 :)

Comment: @Olivier: In this case, we can take the sum from $1$ to $mk$ to get the integral from $0$ to $m$. Then carefully let $m\to\infty$.

Comment: Any idea what's behind the "careful" ? This key point (to bound the rest) is as important as the computation and should be displayed in the solution.

Comment: @Olivier: I believe one can use Abel's Test to estimate the remainder.

Comment: @robjohn Yup, I used the complex argument and then took the limit as k approached infinity to get that. Fantastic answer, I really liked the first approach as it's something I never really thought of haha

Comment: @Olivier: I have added a section showing one method to control the remainders. It is a bit long, to include a lot of detail, but quite typical for this kind of Riemann Sum.

Comment: Here they are, the uniform bounds on the remainders ! :-) Nice tricks.